# execute action every 3 seconds instead of clicking a button action

Tags: jquery, time

I have a script like:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var sliderInstance = $('#content-slider').mySlider({
            directionNavEnabled: true,
            directionNavAutoHide: false,
            welcomeScreenEnabled:false,
            imageAlignCenter:true               

        }).data('mySlider');                
        $("#button-id").click(function() {
            sliderInstance.next();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I make execute **sliderInstance.next();** every 3 seconds instead of clicking **#button-id**

Comment: I'm interested in knowing about specifying an object method in `window.setInterval()` and `window.setTimeout()`

Comment: `setInterval(function() {window.sliderInstance.next() }, 3000);` does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a synthetic click event every 3 seconds, if you like. This requires a minimal amount of extra code:

```
setInterval(function() { $("#button-id").click(); }, 3000);
```

This will generate a click event on the button every 3 seconds.

If you'd rather have it call the script directly:

```
setInterval(function() { sliderInstance.next(); }, 3000);
```

Bear in mind however that the `setInterval` call needs to be in the same scope as the definition of `sliderInstance`, which might make the first version slightly easier or harder to implement depending on how your code is structured.

Comment: Considering that the click only executes `sliderInstance.next()`, this seems rather pointless - why not `setInterval` to call `sliderInstance.next()` directly?

Comment: That is true. I assumed he wanted a click event as well. I'll update with another version.